# javascript onchange undefind error | is no defined

Tags: javascript

when i change the list value it show me "getstate is not defined" 
how to fix it

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="getstate();">
                                <option value="">select</option>
                                <option value="1">USA</option>                               
                            </select>
function getstate() {
                    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url();?>"; 
                    var countryid = $("#country").val();
                    if(countryid=="") {
                     $("#state").html('<option value="">select</option>');
                     $("#city").html('<option value="">select</option>');
                            return false;
                    }
                    $.get(site_url+"admin/ajxcal1",{'id':countryid},function(data){
                    console.log(data);  
                    //$("#state").html(data);
                    });     
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All javascript code should be wrapped inside a script tag. It should work then.

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="getstate();">
                                    <option value="">select</option>
                                    <option value="1">USA</option>                               
                                </select>
<script>function getstate() {
                    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url();?>"; 
                    var countryid = $("#country").val();
                    if(countryid=="") {
                     $("#state").html('<option value="">select</option>');
                     $("#city").html('<option value="">select</option>');
                            return false;
                    }
                    $.get(site_url+"admin/ajxcal1",{'id':countryid},function(data){
                    console.log(data);  
                    //$("#state").html(data);
                    });     
            }</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't matter whether your js function is below your html code. verify it and correct your sentence. don't misguide.

Comment: I agree with the second part, however, before the script runs, the Javascript interpreter runs through the code and defines all functions defined using the syntax "function myFunc(){}", so the function actually is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Add your js function into a seperate .js file or in a script tag in html, Then it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="getstate()">
     <option value="">select</option>
     <option value="1">USA</option>                               
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
     function getstate() {
            var site_url = "<?php echo site_url();?>"; 
            var countryid = $("#country").val();
               if(countryid=="") {
                $("#state").html('<option value="">select</option>');
                $("#city").html('<option value="">select</option>');
                return false;
               }
            $.get(site_url+"admin/ajxcal1",{'id':countryid},function(data){
            console.log(data);  
            //$("#state").html(data);
            });     
         }
</script>
```